# DataFrame.any() returns 'True' when all rows shows 'False' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python

I am analysing job satisfactions of TAFE Australia, and trying to use `DataFrame.any()` to identify whether 'True' exists in any of the columns related to job dissatisfactory factors.

The expected out come is my code should return `'True'` to the new column `'dissatisfied'` if true value exits under any of the job dissatisfaction columns, otherwise return `'False'`.

However, my codes seem to return `'True'` in many rows that none 'True' value exists. I've pasted my code below. Does anyone know where I've gone wrong here please?

```
tafe_resignation['dissatisfied'] = tafe_resignation.iloc[:,0:22].any(axis = 1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they `"False"` (a string, interpreted as `True`) or `False` (a boolean)?

Comment: Oh you are right! I didn't change the type to boolean. But when I change them to boolean, a lot of the `'False'` changed to `'True'` which changed the data set completely, is there a way I might be able to prevent this from happening please?

Comment: I used `tafe_resignation.iloc[:,0:22] = tafe_resignation.iloc[:,0:22]=='True'` to convert the objects to boolean values, it worked! Not sure if there's any better ways to do this though. Thank you so much for your help!